# Create new column for each unique item (word) with frequency count

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and programming in general and have been struggling with the following.

I have a dataframe like below:

```
id     animals
 1     cat dog
 2     cat pig dog fish fish
 3     horse horse
```

I want to create a new column for each animal containing the frequency count for each id :

```
id    cat  dog  fish  horse  pig
 1     1    1     0     0     0
 2     1    1     2     0     1
 3     0    0     0     2     0
```

How do I achieve this?

example dput:

```
structure(list(id = 1:3, animals = structure(1:3, .Label = c("cat dog", 
    "cat pig dog fish fish", "horse horse"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
    "animals"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
df %>%
    separate_rows(animals) %>%
    count(id, animals) %>%
    spread(animals, n, fill = 0)
## A tibble: 3 x 6
#     id   cat   dog  fish horse   pig
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    1.    1.    1.    0.    0.    0.
#2    2.    1.    1.    2.    0.    1.
#3    3.    0.    0.    0.    2.    0.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "id     animals
 1     'cat dog'
 2     'cat pig dog fish fish'
 3     'horse horse'", header = T)
```

Comment: Instead of mutate and unnest you can use separate_rows

Comment: Indeed @kath and thanks!

Comment: And spread has a fill option, where you can specify `fill = 0`

Comment: Right again @kath; it's clearly getting too late here. I should sign off.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner with `data.table` might be:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, unlist(strsplit(as.character(animals), " ")), by = id], id ~  V1)

#  id cat dog fish horse pig
#1  1   1   1    0     0   0
#2  2   1   1    2     0   1
#3  3   0   0    0     2   0
```

---

Or as another option you could use `dcast` in `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
spl <- strsplit(as.character(df$animals), " ")
df_m <- data.frame(id = rep(df$id, times = lengths(spl)), animals = unlist(spl))
dcast(df_m, id ~ animals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may choose `unnest_tokens` from `tidytext`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

x %>%  unnest_tokens(word,animals) %>%  table()
```

**Data:**

```
x <- structure(list(id = 1:3, animals = c("cat dog", "cat pig dog fish fish", 
"horse horse")), .Names = c("id", "animals"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

**OUtput**:

```
   word
id  cat dog fish horse pig
  1   1   1    0     0   0
  2   1   1    2     0   1
  3   0   0    0     2   0
```

Just on the side note: I love this book , in case you are interested in tidytext analysis, its a must read: https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html